# Phone gap form not submitting to server

Tags: javascript, forms, cordova

I have this form

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p class="no_margin-bottom">Merchant name</p>
                            <input type="text" name="login merchant name" id="login_merchant_name" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <p class="no_margin-bottom">Merchant password</p>
                            <input type="password" name="login merchant password" id="login_merchant_password" class="form-control">
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                    </form>
```

and this is the js for it

```
 $("#login_form").submit(function(e)
{
    $("#loading_div").show();

 var inputs = [];
    var res = true;

    inputs[0] = document.getElementById("login_merchant_name");
    inputs[1] = document.getElementById("login_merchant_password");

    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        if (inputs[i].value === "")
        {

            inputs[i].style.background = "#ffcccc";
            res = false;
            $("#loading_div").hide();
                    toastr.error(inputs[i].name + ' must not be empty');

        } else
        {
            inputs[i].style.background = "#fff";
        }

    }



    if (res === true)
    {


         data = $(this).serialize();

       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       crossDomain: true,

       timeout: 5000,
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       cache: false,
       url: "http://gbelo.com/app/process.php", //Relative or absolute path to            response.php file
       data: data,


       success: function(data) {

       if(data.status === 'success'){
$("#loading_div").hide();
toastr.success('Login successful');

var merchant_id = data.merchant_id;
alert(merchant_id);

    setTimeout(function() {
  window.top.location.href='home.html';
          }, 2000);
}else if(data.status === 'incorrect password'){
    $("#loading_div").hide();
    toastr.error('Incorrect password');
}else if(data.status === 'name does not exist'){
    $("#loading_div").hide();
    toastr.error('invalid merchant name');
}


       }
       });




}

       e.preventDefault();
});
```

The form validation works well and it tends to submit, but it doesn't get any response from the server. I have tried the server side code with the same form and it works but it doesn't seem to be working with phone gap.

Please take a look at my code and point out my mistakes.

Comment: Did you test it in google chrome, check out the dev console if any error messages are being throwed

Comment: console only shows these errors. 1) GET file:///Users/Cashmere/Documents/Phonegap-projects/Gbelo!/www/js/jquery.simple-text-rotator.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
login.html:55           2)GET file:///Users/Cashmere/Documents/Phonegap-projects/Gbelo!/www/cordova.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2login.html:1              3)Font from origin 'http://gbelo.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.  And all these can't stop it from working

Comment: Okay so it's a CORS problem, let me post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first you have to add this to your `res/xml/config.xml` file `<access origin="*"/>` then in your php file add this before all 
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');`

**UPDATE**

Install this cordova plugin `org.apache.cordova.whitelist`

> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.whitelist

Then add this to your `config.xml` file

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
    $.ajax({
                    url: "http://gbelo.com/app/process.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            // handle success
                            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            // handle error
                            console.error("The following error occurred: "+textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
            });
```

Try this ajax request

Comment: the <access origin="*"/> was already in the config file. I added the codes to the php file but still not working

Comment: Did you try the app directly on your android phone ?

Comment: yer. it just shows the loading div and its supposed to remove that when the sucess/error response comes

Comment: already have it installed and have that code in the xml but not working

Comment: still no response. Even changed the php file just to send a success report.    if (isset($_POST["login_merchant_name"])) { 
        
       
                       $response['status'] = 'success';  
                      
echo json_encode($response);
    
    

        
        
    }

Comment: Well comment all your php file and just put this in
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`
`echo var_dump($_POST);`
Then let me know what's showing up on the chrome console

Comment: Hold on did you add this to your index.html file `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Comment: it removes all the styling and the  the ajax submit doesn't work

Comment: solved it. The problem was from the host for the server. Changed host and everything worked well. Thanks for your assistance